# IBM Silverpop push integration in Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, push-notification

I need to migrate an old app writen in Objective-C to Swift.
This app uses IBM solution Silverpop for push notifications.

I am having some troubles during my migration with the Silverpop solution. 
The framework is written in Objective-C and when I follow the documentation or sample on GitHub (there is difference between doc and sample..) I cannot get the app to work.

The App crashes in `main.swift` that the documentation asked me to create with:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

UIApplicationMain(CommandLine.argc, nil, nil, "MCEAppDelegate")
```

On launch the app crashes with:

```
Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x8)
```

Documentation : https://developer.ibm.com/customer-engagement/tutorials/getting-started-mobile-app-messaging-ios-apps/

Sample : https://github.com/ibm-mobile-push/ios/tree/master/samples/Swift%20Automatic%20Sample/SwiftSample

my MceConfig.json

```
{
    "baseUrl": "https://api.ibm.xtify.com/3.0/",
    "appKey": {
        "dev":"xxxx",
        "prod":"xxxx"
    },
    "appDelegateClass": "AppDelegate",
    "autoInitializeFlag": true,
    "sessionTimeout": 20,
    "metricTimeInterval": 180,
    "loglevel": "verbose",
    "logfile": false
}
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: What does the console say when it crashes?

Comment: Nothing at all except the EXC_BAD_ACCESS .. I saw that this problem could be related to Objective-C bad memory access. But I don't know how to fix it because it's not my code but the IBM framework code.

Comment: According to the doc, you need so many setups. Have you done it properly? Please show your MceConfig.json (exclude `appKey` of course).

Comment: In UIApplicationMain, the first argument is the count of command line arguments that were passed to the function.  The second argument is supposed to be a list of those arguments.  In this case if CommandLine.argc is greater than zero then the second argument should not be nil.  Could that be the case?  What happens if you replace CommandLine.argc with 0?

Comment: @ScottThompson black screen with 0, and there is the same main.swift content in the github sample.

Comment: @OOPer I have updated my post with MceConfig content

Answer (score 0):

Your MceConfig.json is not following the doc and the note in the sample code.

[Setting up the sample app that is included in the Mobile App Messaging SDK for iOS.](https://developer.ibm.com/customer-engagement/tutorials/13435/)

> 2. Swift requires your class to be in a namespace. For this reason, if you are using the Swift Sample App, update the “appDelegateClass”
>      value to “SwiftSample.AppDelegate”.

[MceConfig.json](https://github.com/ibm-mobile-push/ios/blob/master/MceConfig.json) in the sample code:

> ```
> "Please note: if you are using a Swift based Application Delegate you must include the product name and class name in AppDelegateClass, for example": "SwiftSample.AppDelegate",
> "appDelegateClass": "AppDelegate",
> ```

Try changing the line in your MceConfig.json
From:

```
"appDelegateClass": "AppDelegate",
```

To:

```
"appDelegateClass": "YourAppProductName.AppDelegate",
```

(Replace `YourAppProductName` to the actual product name of your app.)

Comment: already tried, nothing changed. I think this is not an error in config, if it was the case, I will have logs of SDK init trying to load MceConfig, no?

Comment: @EmmanuelLoisance, As far as I tested, giving bad value to MceConfig.json is the only way to crash my app at startup. You may have other faults in your settings or codes, but remember you need to keep the right value to `"appDelegateClass"` as described above.

Comment: I have copy and paste MceConfig.json content, update appDelegateClass and keys, try to move MceConfig.json in and out of product folder.. no way. I use Pods to get Silverpop framework, some more things to do ?

Comment: Sorry, but I have never used Pods, so I cannot say anything if using the Pods affects or not. Anyway the class `MCEAppDelegate` loads `MceConfig.json` and then instantiates the class taken with `appDelegateClass`. Your app is stopping anywhere in this process. Class definition of `MCEAppDelegate` cannot be found, or `MceConfig.json` is broken or not included in your app bundle or... Consider all that things in mind and check one by one.